# node.js - how to push an address change to a client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set up a simple presentation using three computers synchronized by a central server, and I figured node would be the ideal tool.

I was wondering if there's any way to have all three computers connect to the server via the browser, and if I could control the server to push changes to each?

For example:

`Computer-1` visits `10.0.0.1?comp=1?slide=1`

`Computer-2` visits `10.0.0.1?comp=2?slide=1`

`Computer-3` visits `10.0.0.1?comp=3?slide=1`

Then from the server commandline, I would like to be able to trigger a change so the clients will each be redirected accordingly like so:

`Computer-1` visits `10.0.0.1?comp=1?slide=2`

`Computer-2` visits `10.0.0.1?comp=2?slide=2`

`Computer-3` visits `10.0.0.1?comp=3?slide=2`

I'm new to node, so I'm not even sure if this is the ideal platform, but was wondering what terminology I should be researching to be able to build something like this?

Comment: Server-sent events or websockets.

Comment: From your point, it is eveident that you need server push technology. So here you need to use node socket.io library which is built on top of websocket technology...Also you can use Long Polling here as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, I ended up looking into [socket.io](http://socket.io) and managed to write this system in one evening! Node + socket.io and express is a pretty amazing tool with the socket emit events.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, this is exactly the tool I was looking for.

Just in case it may help anyone, in my client/jade template, I have something like:

```
socket.on('slideUpdate', function (data) {
  // Do things with the data
}
```

and on the server `app.js`:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('slideChange', function (data) {
    // logic for setting slide data
    io.sockets.emit('slideUpdate', { example: exampleData ... });
  });
});
```

where a `slideChange` event is triggered via a button on the client-side template.

Answer (score 0):

For such a presentation I would use the most simple solution, i.e. **not** websockets, not server-sent events and not long-polling.

Just do a short poll, i.e. every client calls the server every 100ms for updates. The server then responds with a status update (if there is one).